# GetElementsByName не работает HTML\JS

Tags: html, javascript

у меня есть вот такой скрипт :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="EventHandlers.js">

<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        if(document) {
            alert("1");
            if(document.body){
                alert("2");
                if(document.body.getElementById("myButtonId")){
                    alert("3");
                    if(document.body.getElementsByName("myButton").onclick){
                        alert("4");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        document.body.getElementsByName("myButton").onclick= loadXMLDoc;
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv" data-widgetName="menu">
<label id="myLabel">Select the genre</label>
<input id="myButtonId" type="button" name="myButton" value="myButtonValue"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

в нем, алерт(3) не вызывается, непонятно почему.
Если в условии if убрать dom-узел  body:

```
 document.getElementById("myButtonId")
```

То все работает, почему так?(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `getElementsByName` возвращает **массив** элементов. Соответственно доступ к каждому найденному можно получить посредством указания индекса:

```
document.body.getElementsByName("myButton")[0]
```

В Вашем коде Вы пытаетесь повесить обработчик на массив, а не на конкрентный элемент.

Comment: Спасибо!
PS а как изменится поведение, если повесить на массив?

Comment: Да вообщем-то обработчик вообще не будет работать. Для того чтобы повесить его на массив элементов, надо их перебрать и повесить на каждый отдельно.